# Setting up isolated COM for multiple projects

Tags: c#, .net, regfreecom

My solution consists of multiple projects all of which out type class library except one whose output type is windows application. The application references all the other projects. I also have a COM component which is referenced by some of the projects and the application also.

I can setup the regfree COM by changing the Isolated property of the referenced COM component in visual studio to TRUE. The solution builds successfully and I can see the manifest file generated for that particular assembly or application.

Now, my question is that do I need to do this for all the projects which reference the COM component? If yes, then I know that i cannot set the Isolated property to TRUE on more than one project(gives a build error) so how do I workaround this?

I am relatively new to .net and don't know much regfree COM(i assume what i am doing IS regfree COM?). Any help I can get on this issue is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

I am currently using VS 2008.

EDIT: When the Isolated Property is set to TRUE for multiple projects the build error says that myCOMcomponent.ocx is defined in the generated manifests for both the projects.

Comment: Don't make us guess at the build error.

Comment: @Hans: I edited the post with the build error. Let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can only isolate each COM component once per application. That's why you get an error. You can work around this if you make a wrapper library that exposes the functionality in that component, and then have everything else call that wrapper, instead of the COM component directly. This way you have only one reference to the COM component, and thus need to isolate it only once.